# What does the 'native' keyword mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, native, token, keyword

I stumbled upon a function called `v8Locale` in Chrome's Developer Console. I was curious so I entered the function to get the source code, and it revealed the following code:

```
function (a){
native function NativeJSLocale();
var b=NativeJSLocale(a);
this.locale=b.locale;
this.language=b.language;
this.script=b.script;
this.region=b.region;
}
```

I started searching on the Internet and found [this file](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/extensions/experimental/i18n.js?spec=svn7620&r=7620) which seems to be the source (it looks like it has been minified though).

I have no idea what the `native` keyword means here. When I try to make something like this myself:

```
function bar() {}

function foo() {
    native function bar();
}
```

I get the following error message (as I expected, actually):

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token native
```

How is it possible that the `v8Locale` function contains the `native` token, and what does it mean/do?

Comment: Source path `src/extensions/experimental/i18n.js`. Sounds like a chrome extension file. You can write chrome extensions in a superset of JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe it's the code of the browser. For example if you see `window.history.back` in Chromes console, and you see `function () { [native code] }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is used to tell `v8` that the function is implemented in C++ code

Comment: Note that *native* does not imply `C++`. It could be any language, Mozilla has been using `Java`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `native` keyword is not defined in the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Sounds like it's part of a chrome extension

Comment: It's not defined, but it is reserved... so there are most certainly some people who have an idea of what it's for!

Comment: @AlexisWilke It was reserved because it's a keyword in Java. Same with public, private, volatile, synchronized, transient, etc. This isn't quite hard and fast, though. I think the reserved a few others just in case.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Why would keywords in Java be relevant to the Javascript language? You say "just in case" ... just in case what happens?

Comment: @LukeGriffiths I realize the languages are actually very different, but the syntax is very similar, the "Java" bit of the name was at least intentional, and it makes sense to reserve keywords that similar, contemporary languages use. Java reserved `goto` and `const` because of C and C++. Here's the Javascript list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords . It's pretty obvious what "just in case" is if you look at the list (especially the ES v1-v3 list).

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_words), the `native` word is no longer reserved in javascript. Is also usable in Node JS:

```
alec@MacBook-Air ~/process/tmp/shed/cli (main) $ node -v
v16.9.1
alec@MacBook-Air ~/process/tmp/shed/cli (main) $ node
...
> let native = 'XLM'
undefined
> console.log(native)
XLM
undefined
>
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript, which is also based on ECMAScript, defines the native keyword here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#native

They offer an example with code:

```
native function functionName();
class className { 
  native function methodName();
}
```

And there is the description:

> Specifies that a function or method is implemented by Flash Player in native code. Flash Player uses the native keyword internally to declare functions and methods in the ActionScript application programming interface (API). This keyword cannot be used in your own code.

As implied by Matt, functions marked as native are implemented in the interpreter so you cannot yourself define a native function (unless you tweak the source code of your JavaScript interpreter...)